# Get ORA 01722 invalid number when try to copy data from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to admin there is slight difference between the columns from both tables. But I thought that was minor.

The table Source has three attributes

```
Amount     NUMBER(10,2)
SHORTNAME  VARCHAR2(3)
NAME       VARCHAR2(40)
```

The table Target has the same set of attributes but slightly different constraints on their type

```
Amount     NUMBER
SHORTNAME  VARCHAR2(255)
NAME       VARCHAR2(255)
```

I thought table `Target` should have more tolerance on its capacity, but when I run the query

```
insert into DB_B.Target select * from DB_A.Source ;
```

Unfortunately I get the popular 01722 error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number -- 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

So when we say when copying data from two tables with the same schema, are we talking about 100% IDENTICAL even on the TYPE CONSTRAINT?

Please help.

## Update

Before thunder storm hit the office, I have to mention that the column order on both tables are different. Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name help me think out this issue and give the perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the order of the columns is not identical in the two tables.

Try to explicitely list the columns to make sure they aren't mixed up for some reason:

```
insert into db_b.target 
    (amount, shortname, name) 
select amount, shortname, name 
from db_a.source;
```

Note that it's generally considered bad style to *not* list the columns in the insert clause and to use `select *` in that way (even if that isn't the cause of your problem)

Comment: WoW, that's fast! And it works ! The horse must have a name XD

Comment: @Subarule: if that really fixes it, then you just learned the hard way way insert without a column list and `select *` are evil!

Comment: Right, I forget to mention the order of columns are different too. Have a nice weekend !

Comment: @Subarule: But typing this question took you far longer than typing the three columns would have taken in the first place. Besides: good SQL clients can help you there (through auto-completion aka "intellisense")